# Can we have Fractal bases like Fourier basis?

Tags: linear-algebra, functional-analysis, soft-question, image-processing

As I understand we can perform a Fourier transform (2 dimensional ) on a class of matrix and get Fourier coefficients; and from those coefficients we can get back the original matrix. In other words Fourier coefficients forms a one to one map with the original matrix. Not sure I am expressing my self correctly mathematically but I hope it is understood. The question is if such bases exist in fractal domain? The wikipedia link of fractal is :

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fractal

I can understand the kind of matrix for which the fractal bases exist may be very limited and Fourier bases exist for much broader class of matrix. I am interested to know what kind of matrix has the fractal kind of basis? Mostly can we transform a matrix so that it has a fractal bases?

Comment: What fractal domain in particular ? And do you know the Haar discrete wavelet transform ?

Comment: @user1952009 Very good point, When I asked this question I forgot about wavelet. Do you know the difference between wavelet and fractal?

Comment: The Haar wavelet transform is an orthogonal linear operator sending $f \in L^2([0,1])$ to $g \in L^2(X)$ where $X = \bigcup_{n \ge 0} \mathbb{Z}_{2^n}$ is a fractal space

Comment: @user1952009 Thank you.If you write like an answer I will accept it.

Comment: @user1952009 General fractal do have non integer dimension; in that sense: Is the scale of wavelet equivalent to dimension of fractals?